# Trouble adding a URL rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect the URL:

```
http://goalcandy.com/workspace/edit
```

to the following

```
http://goalcandy.com/?module=workspace&editgb=1
```

And just can't add a correct rule that will work. Please help.
Oh, if it makes any difference, I already have a working rewrite rule in place for just the *workspace* page:

```
RewriteRule ^workspace/$ /workspace [R]
RewriteRule ^workspace$ index.php?module=workspace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to it:

```
RewriteRule ^workspace/edit/$ /workspace/edit [R]
RewriteRule ^workspace/edit$ index.php?module=workspace&editgb=1
```